# How to cover 'Import communityPath from '@salesforce/community/basePath'; in Jest (for LWC)

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-community, lwc-jest

cmp.js File

```
Import communityPath from '@salesforce/community/basePath';
```

test.js File

```
jest.mock( 
    '@salesforce/community/basePath',
    ()=>({ default : '/mocked/community/basePath'}),
);
```

But while testing getting error - Cannot find module '@salesforce/community/basePath'. Any ways to cover this in Jest.